# Information missing from Reliabiliy Monitor after windows update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, event-viewer, windows-10-v21h1

After installing Cumulative Update July 2021 for Windows 10 21H1 [KB5004237](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/july-13-2021-kb5004237-os-builds-19041-1110-19042-1110-and-19043-1110-ae798d3c-3de3-4c1f-b9d9-7391b71da889) I have got the following errors on my computer.

Reliability Monitor doesn't show all the events. The following are missing.

- Miscellaneous failures
- Warnings
- Information

[image: reliability has events missing after windows update]

I'm using Windows 10 21H1. I do not want to do a system restore point for security reasons to prevent getting viruses or hacked. I can't find the relevant events in Event Monitor as there's too many of them for me to know what to look for.

How do I get them to appear back again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started to work from the 14th of August onwards after running windows update along with it running self-repairing windows updates.

These self-repairing windows updates would run in the background behind the scenes, so there would be nothing visible in the Windows Update screen to show that any updates are available or installing. Windows 10 is self-correcting (unlike Windows 8) where it monitors the way you use your computer to turn features on and off behind the scenes at the back-end level (eg. Known Issue Rollback).

[image: windows update is up to date]

All while it was saying "up to date" on the windows update screen, however in task manager the following programs were running in the background for multiple days at different times.

- Windows Module Installer
- Windows Module Installer Worker
- [Waas Medic Service](https://tipsmake.com/what-is-waasmedic-how-to-disable-waasmedic) (Windows Update Medic Service) (windows as a service) (this rarely runs when installing windows updates)
- [MoUSO Core Worker Process](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-mousocoreworker-exe)

So it eventually got fixed by windows itself due to microsoft's doing for computers in certain conditions without any input from myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this version with the July 13 2021 update installed. I use Reliability History a lot.

The error content has most likely been removed by cleanups that happen. I have not seen cleanup so close to "today" unless deliberate.

Most of the errors are application errors (not Windows errors) - you can see that at the right of the graph.

You can try several things:

1. At the bottom of the graph, click on View all Problem Reports and see if you can get more information. If you can, that is a source of information for you. If not, then the reports are gone and you cannot retrieve them.
2. You can start the Report again.  In the screen I alluded to above, click on Clear all Problem Reports, do a Disk Cleanup  and when it comes up, click on Clean Up System Files.  Then restart and let the Report build anew. It may (should) give you recent error information this way. You should get details of App errors giving you the app.

To the extent Reliability History reports anew, it should give you the information it has.  If not, something is wrong.

I am not sure what you specifically mean by "Miscellaneous failures, Warnings, Information"  except as Reliability History normally reports.  I use this report a lot myself.

3. An alternative approach  (the above steps do not work):  Since you do have a large number of application reports, you might try doing a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation link.

[Media Creation Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

For the first try, use Keep Everything and when it is done, you will be where you start from, hopefully less the errors. This should not hurt or damage security.